# Displaying a block of php with html and php function call on the html

Tags: php, html, css

all.

I'm handling a if statement where I use php to check if a session language is set. If the variable is set, I'll display some html with it's own php code embedded on the html tags. I already escaped the characters, but I'm still not getting the translation function call response to display on the html.
I'd appreciate any help you could give me for the code below.
Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
if((isset($_SESSION['lang'])) && $_SESSION['lang']=='pt'){
echo("<div class=\"row\">
    <div class=\"col col-12\" style=\"width:100\% !important\">
    <label class=\"radio state-success\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"chosenMethod\" value=\"2\"><i style=\"padding-right:0px !important;\">    
    </i><?php echo getTranslation(\'member\');?></label>
    </div><br>
    <div class=\"col col-12\" style=\"width:100\% !important\">
    <div style=\"font-size:90\%\">echo getTranslation(\'member_choices\');</div>
    </div><br>
    </div>");}
    ?>
```

Comment: Pro tip: wrap your HTML in single quotes instead of double and you'll escape stuff a LOT less (and thus avoid more escaping mistakes)

Comment: I got the escape characters under control, but I can't make the "echo getTranslation('') to work. If I put the function inside php tags, it just won't display. If I take the php tags, the html will render the "echo getTranslation('')" as it's written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
</i><?php echo getTranslation(\'member\');?></label>
```

with

```
</i>" . getTranslation('member') . "</label>
```

Since you are already echoing out the statment, the `;?>` portion is interpreted as the closing tag for the original php statement.

Comment: That did the job, Ashkay. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using `echo`, you tell PHP not to **execute** the following HTML/PHP combo, but to **print** it. So What you want is

```
$member=getTranslation('member');
$memberChoices=getTranslation(\'member_choices\');
echo "<div class=\"row\">
    <div class=\"col col-12\" style=\"width:100\% !important\">
    <label class=\"radio state-success\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"chosenMethod\" value=\"2\"><i style=\"padding-right:0px !important;\">    
    </i>$result</label>
    </div><br>
    <div class=\"col col-12\" style=\"width:100\% !important\">
    <div style=\"font-size:90\%\">$memberChoices</div>
    </div><br>
    </div>";
```

Let me add, that this is not the most elegant way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Fix above as below (you are using `<?php` within `<?php` and `echo` within an `echo`):

```
<?php
if((isset($_SESSION['lang'])) && $_SESSION['lang']=='pt'){

    $translation = getTranslation(member);
    $translation_choice = getTranslation(member_choices);

    echo("<div class=\"row\">
        <div class=\"col col-12\" style=\"width:100\% !important\">
        <label class=\"radio state-success\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"chosenMethod\" value=\"2\"><i style=\"padding-right:0px !important;\">    
        </i>" . $translation . "</label>
        </div><br>
        <div class=\"col col-12\" style=\"width:100\% !important\">
        <div style=\"font-size:90\%\">" . $translation_choice . "</div>
        </div><br>
        </div>");}
    ?>
```